# xpath to fetch values of specific siblings

Tags: xpath

```
<balanceLogicals>
<**balanceDefinitionId>5</balanceDefinitionId**>
<balanceLogicalId>308989</balanceLogicalId>
<balanceResources>
<monthlyRecurDay>1</monthlyRecurDay>
<nextRecurDt>2022-12-01T00:00:00+08:00</nextRecurDt>
<offerCode>GSMS2059-R1-2-INV_TO_ACC</offerCode>
<offerId>1000082</offerId>
<recurType>monthly</recurType>
<recurValue>0</recurValue>
<requestAuthorisation>false</requestAuthorisation>
<resourceBundleId>263068</resourceBundleId>
<resourceId>390890</resourceId>
<rolloverProfileId>1</rolloverProfileId>
</balanceResources>
<**balances**>
<balanceId>6914707</balanceId>
<fromDt>2022-11-23T11:05:20+08:00</fromDt>
<initialValue>0</initialValue>
<offerId>1000082</offerId>
<overdraft>false</overdraft>
<resourceId>390890</resourceId>
<toDt>2022-11-30T23:59:59+08:00</toDt>
**<value>123456</value>**
</**balances**>
<holdFromDt>2022-11-23T11:05:20+08:00</holdFromDt>
<reason>owner</reason>
<thresholds>
<threshold3ActionId>100BOOSTNOTIFY</threshold3ActionId>
<threshold3Status>ACTIONED</threshold3Status>
<threshold3Value>0</threshold3Value>
</thresholds>
<value>0</value>
</balanceLogicals>
```

I want to fetch values for the element \balances\value for only specific set of **balanceDefinitionId**

In my response there are multiple **balanceDefinitionId** but I am interesed in only for few to fetch and use.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be

```
/balanceLogicals[balanceDefinitionId='5']/balances/value
```

which will result in `123456`.
But you can also use

```
//balances[../balanceDefinitionId='5']/value
```

The result in both cases should be the same: `123456`.

Of course `5` is only the placeholder for your desired condition.

Comment: Thanks for your help , this works for me. Can we also do sum on values returned from above xpath for different balanceDefinitionId. For example if I want to get the sum of balanceDefinitionId='5' and balanceDefinitionId='13' in my response.